# How to forcefully remove a package marked rH by dpkg?

Tags: apt, dpkg, uninstall

I tried to install the Canon CQue driver for my printer by downloading the .deb file from Canon's website and installing it with

`dpkg -i filename.deb`

The installation didn't finish and I always get an error when doing `apt upgrade`. I listed the status by `sudo dpkg -l | grep cqu` and it was listed as `iF`.

I read the man page for `dpkg-query`, but I don't know what "Half installed" means. So I tried uninstalling it with `sudo dpkg -r cque-en`, but I got an error. I tried to `sudo apt install --fix-broken`, but that fails too with the error:

```
Removing cque-en (4.0-6) ...
dpkg: error processing package cque-en (--remove):
 installed cque-en package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 cque-en
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Now the result of `sudo dpkg -l | grep cqu` is

```
rH  cque-en  4.0-6   amd64  CQue - Driver for Canon iR, CLC, LPB and MF laser devices (English).
```

`sudo apt remove` gives me the same error as above.

What does the error status 127 mean anyway? And how do I remove a package marked as `rH` by dpkg? Is there a way to force it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing

`sudo rm -f /var/lib/dpkg/info/cque-en.postrm`

(whereas the `-f` is probably not needed).

Not the nicest of solutions, but at least I can update and upgrade my system without getting any error message and everything seems to be working just fine for the time being.

Comment: Fair solution generally works, the canonical answer is to raise a bug report. Would you set this answer as accepted which make it visible and easier to be found.

Comment: Removing this file from `/var/lib/dpkg/info` will cause more and more and more and more and more issues. This is the post-removal file, removing this may cause more issues if the package is reinstalled; removed; messed or something similar happens.

Comment: @Someone I got lucky :-) I haven't had an error message since then and everything seems to be working fine. I hope it stays that way.